# PYTHON-2.x Syntax error on line 1 but i don't see any?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-2.x

the following file is located in this directory: `/Users/whiteglider/Documents`

name of file: `server.py`

this is my practice code which i just copied from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

```
    import socket

    s=socket.socket()
    host=socket.gethostname()
    port=12345
    s.bind((host,port))

    s.listen(5)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        c.send ('Thank you for connecting')
        c.close()
```

when i run it at Terminal, i type

```
$ python /Users/whiteglider/Documents/server.py
```

then i get:

```
File "/Users/whiteglider/Documents/server.py", line 1
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf949\cocoasubrtf540
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

even if i change directory going to where the server.py file actually is and run

```
python server.py
```

i still get the same result.

(mac leopard 10.5.8)

Comment: A good practice for finding Syntax errors in Python is to find Syntax errors in English.  The word "I", for example, is never written in lower-case.  Never.  Practice fixing that kind of thing and the Python syntax errors will follow.

Comment: @S.Lott Not helpful in this particular case.

Comment: @agf: Syntax is syntax.  It matters.  A lot.  English syntax matters as much as Python syntax.  A question full of English syntax errors is a bit of a problem to answer because it indicates larger and more profound problems being "careful" and "precise" as required by writing software.

Comment: Yes, but he could look at his code forever in his editor and never find a Syntax Error, because the problem was the file format, not the code.

Comment: @agf: That's my point.  Care.  Precision.  Accuracy.  Detail.  Focus.  All important in getting the English correct.  Also helpful in realizing the file format is wrong.  It's all the same set of skills.

Answer (score 8):

You've saved the file as a Rich Text Format file rather than a plain text file.

I don't know what editor you're using, but make sure to save the file as plain text / ASCII text, something like that, not RTF.

Comment: Possibly using TextEdit.app.  If so, you can convert the file to plain text with the menu option `Format -> Make Plain Text`.

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! I didn't check the setting of my TextEdit, it was indeed set to rtf so upon saving, though I renamed the extension to .py, I didn't think it will retain the rtf format. Thanks! And regarding the usage of "i" instead of "I", thanks for reminding too. I guess getting lax with few small things makes one prone to error on other important things!  I tried making a simple Hello World and it did run!  I APPRECIATE YOUR TIMELY RESPONSE, MORE POWER!

Answer (score 0):

The 'line continuation character' is typically a backslash at the end of a line.
However, I don't see any in your example.

Can you run a simple 'hello world' app, like the following?

```
print 'hello world'
```

(save the above in the file hello.py, and run)

Does python run fine from an interactive prompt?

Possibly related: what kind of line endings does your file have? '\n' or '\r\n'? I don't think it should matter, but who knows...

Comment: Take a closer look at the error -- he's got other characters in the file than what he showed in the code block.